# redirect all requests to another domain using .htaccess but keeping the original url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a CMS running on **cms.com** that handles login to all my customer. Currently my customers have to go to **cms.com** to access the panel.

I want them to access the same CMS using their own domains such as **customerdomain.com/admin** while keeping the urls.

So, a given request such as posts.php?id=1 which is accessed as **cms.com/posts.php?id=1** should be accessed by customerdomain as **customerdomain.com/admin/posts.php?id=1**

Comment: Are both domain names pointed to the same host?

Comment: You are, more or less, trying to implement a proxy for certain urls.

Comment: No @SergeyMitroshin, they are all in different servers, I used to clone the scripts but updating became hard.

Comment: @Sumurai8 yes, I believe that would somekind work as a proxy, is this possible with htaccess?

Comment: I am not used to doing this, so I won't be writing an answer. See [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) for some information. I can say that if you do this, implement it in httpd.conf or whatever the main configuration file is. I don't know if https is supported (which you probably want to do considering this is admin space). You might want to consider to proxy from a subdomain instead and see if that performs better.

Comment: You can do that with a help mod_proxy, but it's bad idea - your server will making the http request every time.

Comment: @Eugeny Its ok for the server to be making the requests (proxying). Having a look at mod_proxy

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^admin/(.*)$" "http://cms.com/$1" [P]
```

Comment: This redirects the requests to the correct scripts but also changes the url (takes me there)

Comment: Are you issuing any redirects on your backend server? I've tested it and it works fine for me.

Comment: @darkcoder maybe in the page has a javascript which is checking domain name and if not the same, then it redirect you to the parent page.

Comment: yes because there is another htaccess with redirects on the target page it breaks it.

Comment: @darkcoder Well in that case you will need `ProxyPassReverse` to change the redirect so it points to the correct location. Unfortunately this directive can't be used in an htaccess file and must be set in the server config.

Comment: @Chris yes that breaks us since some clients are running on shared servers and we cant change the servers config. Ended up solving with subdomain, wrote as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have solved using A type DNS records. What we did was, for each client we created a subdomain **(admin.sitename.com)** and an **A type record** for the subdomain **admin.sitename.com** pointing to the CMS's server IP.